# Spring Boot @Scheduled - combine cron expression

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron

I have a job that has to execute every day at
7;30
11;00
17;00
21;30

So I was wondering if it is possible to combine this into a single cron expression. As of now the only solution I have is to use two scheduled annotations with 2 cron expressions due to the hours which are non-exact e.g. 7;30 and 21;30

```
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 11,17 * * *") // every day at 11 and 17
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 7,21 * * *") // every day at 7;30 and 21;30
    public void doSomething()
    {

    }
```

Is there a way to combine this into a single cron expression or I have to stick to this approach?

Comment: I'm afraid so you should use both of them. because you have to specify the minutes before hours in cron.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring-Boot one @Scheduled task using multiple cron expressions from yaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929161/spring-boot-one-scheduled-task-using-multiple-cron-expressions-from-yaml-file)